# Problem creating table of content page in HTML without ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tableofcontents

How can the following toc entry

```
<li role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="h1_37_3_anchor" id="h1_37_3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
  <a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="h1_37_3_anchor">
    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i> 
آدَابُ الدُّعَاءِ   دعا کے آداب   
 </a>
</li>
```

be linked to following HTML content without ID?

```
<span class="ma mb1 mi0 mul0 mal1 ms22">
آدَابُ الدُّعَاءِ 
<span class="mu mb1 mi0 mul0 ms22">دعا کے آداب</span>
</span>
```

Above code is from a working website. I just cannot understand how it works without ID and specifying JavaScript.
This is only one entry from TOC and content. There are many like above entries.

I want to understand how above code works.

Comment: Wel to StackOverflow. I'm afraid your question as it stands is not clear. Can you please edit it to provide a clearer explanation of what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create toc in html and I want to create like the one in example above i posted. this code use href="#"  to hyper link and there is no java script defined to handle link click and there are no ids are defined where link will go. I want to understand how this can be achieved. where javascript is attached to handle link click. This icode s from a working website

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's no javascript?  Have you tried opening the page after turning off javascript in the browser?  The fact that you have `jstree` implies a `javascript - treeview` which will 100% be using javascript.   It could just be that you can't find the javascript that is in use.

Comment: Even if you happen to find the javascript, there's a chance that the code could be minified, and not be readable either.

Comment: Yes it certainly using javascript but I can not understand and find how javascript is being used. As u can see toc element does not mention on click attribite and elenmet wihich this toc enetry us linked does not have ID attribute. This is what I want to understan how it works without this.

Comment: How it **is** done will depend on the implementation - ask the author or reverse engineer the code (or provide it here and hope someone does the effort for you).  How it **can** be done without onclick and id?  onclick is a very old way to add event handlers that most people no longer user.   Multiple IDs (likely auto-incrementing in this case) is an anti-pattern so should not be used.   Here's a very simple example on how to create a clickable TOC without onclick or ID:  https://jsfiddle.net/uhpx2g8z/

Comment: It's also possible that the TOC is built dynamically from the contents, in which case the code could use `this` to reference the *content*, eg https://jsfiddle.net/uhpx2g8z/1/